# Создание визуального редактора на Java

Tags: java, javafx, java2d

Пытаюсь создать визуальный редактор, где будет возможность перемещать и изменять размеры элементов (что-то вроде упрощенного варианта Scene Builder). 
В качестве элементов выступают:

- текст (одна строка или несколько одним элементом);
- графические изображения.

У текста также должна быть возможность форматирования (жирный, курсив и т.д.).

Я приспособил к этому `javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas` (получился вполне рабочий прототип), но есть некоторые неудобства:

- приходится самому хранить информацию о координатах и другие свойства каждого элемента, отдельно создавать для этого классы, коллекции и т.п., потому что Canvas не хранит информацию о нарисованных на себе элементах;
- приходится вручную передавать координаты, другие параметры, создавать для различных ситуаций - различные методы;
- при визуализации и перемещении любого из элементов приходится перерисовывать весь Canvas со всеми элементами, и делать это довольно часто.

Думается можно найти и другие минусы, другими словами *изобретается велосипед*, и присутствует настойчивое чувство, что всё это можно реализовать более рациональным способом.

Подскажите куда посмотреть и что *лучше* подойдет для решения моей задачи. Программу пишу используя JavaFX. Буду благодарен за любую помощь/любые примеры.